# Difference between two "IF" blocks

Tags: oracle, plsql

1)

```
DECLARE
  total_sales number := 10;
  no_revenue  BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  IF total_sales <= 0 THEN
    no_revenue := TRUE;
  ELSE
    no_revenue := FALSE;
  END IF;
END;
```

2)

```
DECLARE
  total_sales number := 10;
  no_revenue  BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  IF total_sales <= 0 THEN
    no_revenue := TRUE;
  ELSIF total_sales > 0 THEN
    no_revenue := FALSE;
  END IF;
END;
```

Which one is better With respect to performance and why?

PS. Irrespective of the value of `total_sales`

Comment: Your blocks are semantically different because the second will not assign `no_revenue` if `total_sales` is null.

Answer (score 4):

In your particular situation there is no difference - two blocks will give you the same result. But, `IF` constructs are different and you should pay attention to values of operands and what comparison operators you are using in conditions, because `else` clause of the first `IF` block will *catch* everything that doesn't meet `IF` condition. In the second `IF` block, you are being more specific and the value of `no_revenue` variable will be changed only if one of the two conditions is true.

In terms of performance, it would be better to get rid of that `IF` block completely, in this particular situation and rewrite that logic as follows:

```
no_revenue  := (total_sales <= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say #1 is faster, because it does not have to find result of additional "total_sales > 0" in elseif

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in the first one, if total_sales is NULL no_revenue will be false, in the second the code will break, because NULL is not found between any IF.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).